# Windows forms datagridview combobox add row

Tags: winforms, datagridview, combobox, frameworks, entity

I've got a windows form in my C# program that contains a datagridview which itself contains a combobox. Both the gridview and the combobox use a binding source.

The problem is, that I can't add a new row as the combobox prompts the following error:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Both binding sources are populated like so:

```cs
this.werkzeugBindingSource.DataSource = context.Werkzeug.Local.ToBindingList();
this.gruppeBindingSource.DataSource = context.Gruppe.Local.ToBindingList();
```

The context is a Entity Framework 6 context.

How can I set a default value or anything like that? I'd be fine for me if the first element of the combobox was selected by default.

Comment: Is there only just a combobox in your grid or is there others?

Comment: there are textboxes, checkboxes and one or more comboboxes in the grid. When the combobox is removed the error disappears.